# FB.getUserID() function in Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

The `FB.getUserID()` function is not documented inside https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

I see many apps using it. Why is this function not documented? Is it deprecated or what?

Comment: Apart from what Juicy Scripter said – Facebook themselves also say that _undocumented_ methods can change or even be removed at any time without notice, so best to stay away from using them completely.

Answer (score 0):

It's not anywhere stated that `FB.getUserID()` will be deprecated but it's not currently not documented (not even search on Developers site produce any results).

> **Updates to the Javascript SDK**
>
> As announced in May, we have updated the Javascript SDK to limit the publicly exposed interface. This is part of an ongoing process to improve the reliability of the SDK. We have removed access to all internal properties and to methods prefixed with _.

It may be understood that `FB.getUserID()` may not be affected by those changes, but if you still concerned you may use something like this to achieve same thing:

```
var userID = (FB.getAuthResponse() || {}).userID
```